# Не работает атрибут download

Tags: html, css, frontend, шаблоны

Почему не работает атрибут download,Хотя когда я даю ссылке URL фото, которое на компе,все работает, но если я передаю URL фото которое на находится на компе, ссылка перекидывает на страницу этой фотографии.

```
<div class="images">
{% for link in links %}

    <div class="image">
        
        {% if links[link] == 'photo'%}
            <a href="{{ link }}" download="file.png">
                <p>
                    <img  height="400" src="{{ link }}" alt="">
                </p>
            </a>
        {% else %}
            <a href="{{ link }}" download="file.mp4">
                <p>
                    <video src="{{ link }}" height='400' controls='controls'></video>
                </p>
            </a>
        {% endif %}
    </div>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: я без ничего написал атрибут, но у меня все-равно вместо скачивания выдает страницу

Comment: firefoxе тоже не работает

Comment: а где находится файл?